# Entity Framework Uninitialised Collection

Tags: c#, database, linq, entity-framework, collections

Given the following trivial EF example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace EFPlay
{

public class Packet
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Reciever Reciever { get; set; }
}

public class Reciever
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Packet> Packets { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Reciever> Recievers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Packet> Packets { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var db = new Context();
        var reciever = db.Recievers.Create();

    }
}

}
```

At this point the reciever.Packets property is null. Should this not be initialised automatically by EF? Is there any way to ensure that it is?

Comment: what's the problem with checking: (db.Packets != null)?

Comment: I have the same question. Given we're calling .Create() I don't understand why EF isn't creating a proxy for the collection. It feels clumsy to create our own collection instance, which will be different to one from a loaded entity (and won't have any tracking) :(

Answer (score 1):

It's null because you haven't asked Entity Framework to retrieve the association.

There are two ways to do this:

**1 - Lazy Loading**

```
var reciever = db.Recievers.SingleOrDefault();
var receiverPackets = receiver.Packets; // lazy call to DB - will now be initialized
```

I don't like this approach, i personally *turn off lazy loading*, and use the other approach

**2 - Eager Loading**

```
var receiver = db.Receivers.Include("Packets").SingleOrDefault();
```

Which results in a LEFT OUTER JOIN between Receivers and Packets, instead of two calls - which is the case with lazy loading.

Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you initialize it in a constructor... Then you can be sure averytime you use a new instance of that class this field has already been initialized and is ready to use.

PS: I don't like the two 'Reciever Reciever' words on one row. I would be surprised if it would compile.