# MVC 4 EF5 - Add sub-entities error

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am getting an **Object reference not set to an instance of an object** error when trying to add multiple entity levels to my EF context.

Take the following three-level example class structure:

```
public class Forum
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ForumID { get; set; }
    public virtual Forum Forum { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int BlogID { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

For a given Forum, I want to add a new Blog with a new Post:

```
Forum MyForum = context.Forums.Find(1);
Blog MyBlog = new Blog { Name = "My New Blog" };
Post MyPost = new Post { Name = "My New Post" };

MyForum.Blogs.Add(MyBlog); // This WORKS

MyBlog.Posts.Add(MyPost);  // This FAILS

context.SaveChanges();     // We never make it this far
```

I've tried every possible order combination, including placing `context.SaveChanges()` immediately after `.Add(MyBlog)`.  It seems like it's choking because there is no `Blog.ID` to use for `Post.BlogID`, but EF generates temporary key values for use in this situation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints at the answer (and the root problem) can be found at:

- [Entity Framework Uninitialised Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526364/entity-framework-uninitialised-collection)
- [Entity Framework 4.1 Code First - Should many relationship ICollections be initialised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703761/entity-framework-4-1-code-first-should-many-relationship-icollections-be-initi)

The "simple" solution is to manually initialize the Blog.Posts collection:

```
Blog MyBlog = new Blog { Name = "My New Post", Posts = new List<Post>() };
```

Alternatively, you can build this logic into the class constructor as recommended by Ladislav in the second link.

Basically, when you create a new object, the collection is null and not initialized as a List<>, so the `.Add()` call fails.  The Forum.Blogs collection is able to lazy-load because it derives from the database context.  Blog.Posts, however, is created from scratch, and EF can't help you, so the collection is null by default.